# Link statically stdlib.so

Tags: go, build, static-libraries

Following this [blog post](http://blog.ralch.com/tutorial/golang-sharing-libraries/) I tried to compile stdlib.so to link other code with it.  Unfortunately, stdlib.so itself is a dynamically linked binary:

```
# ldd /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64_dynlink/libstd.so
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `/usr/local/go/pkg
/linux_amd64_dynlink/libstd.so'
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd611d7000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f82bb2c5000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f82baf04000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055e99ffd7000)
```

I tried building it with different flags, but that doesn't seem to do anything / not the result I expected.  I.e. I tried:

```
go install -x -buildmode=shared --ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' std
```

for example, but that translates into a wrong set of compiling / linking instructions, so libstd.so isn't produced.

## Rationale

I want to do this because I have several Go programs I need to build and to put them into Docker images.  Statically linking a Go executable takes a long time (roughly a minute, give or take 20 seconds), so I was hoping to compile all the infrequently changing dependencies into a shared library, while only recompiling the actual code of the application (that would decrease the compilation time from about 10 minutes to few seconds).  I would also prefer not to have to base Docker images on some Linux image (that would make them 600+ MB big vs 60 MB of only Go code).

Comment: I am currently building my golang app etc all so it statically linked. It is so good to be able to use the scratch docker image my images are like 2 mg in size. I only do the statically linking on deployment all my CI and dev I dont bother with it

Comment: You can't statically link a 'shared' library. You can statically link a binary, but if you're using cgo, glibc still needs to be dynamically linked.

Comment: yeah sorry, I have cgo disabled but i get what you mean.

Comment: If you want a static _binary_, don't built a shared _library_ with `-buildmode=shared`. If you're not using cgo, what problem are you having building a static binary without the external linker?

Comment: @JimB I didn't word it correctly. I want stdlib.so to be linked statically with libc and libpthread, but I want my code to link dynamically to stdlib.  I don't want a static binary, I want a library that doesn't depend on other libraries. (PS. I can make my Docker image from scratch if I put into it a bunch of *.so files, but I hoped I could just put a single stdlib.so instead).

Comment: While it's possible to link static libraries into a shared object, I don't can't think of a way to wedge that into the Go toolchain. Note what I said earlier, you don't want to statically link glibc, so you would want to use a different libc implementation. Though you say you have cgo disabled, so why are you linking to libc/libpthread at all?

Comment: @JimB Why am I linking libc/libpthread? - Aren't these required by any sort of Go (both C- and the other one)? I seriously don't know. I just saw that these were the dependencies of a compiled program and assumed they just had to be there. And... of course I want to link glibc statically, that's the whole point of what I'm doing. When and if I will want to use a different version, I'll make a different Docker image. It is a matter of convenience for me: I'll prefer to have fewer files in an image, but if it's so hard, meh, I can deal with some extra noise.

Comment: Go only links to libc for cgo, which means you don't have cgo disabled otherwise the binaries are static by default. If you can build your project without cgo, then this isn't an issue.

Comment: @JimB I've set `CGO_ENABLED=0`, removed all `*.a` files and rebuilt. This didn't work: I'm getting an invalid library (in the end of the build it says: `cannot open shared library: $WORK/libstd.so`). When I compile with `-x`, I can see linker trying to link this library, but it doesn't print enough to understand what went wrong.

Comment: I meant you could make a single static go executable without cgo, which may be faster to link, that seems like a lot of time for a pure go program. Maybe the shared mode executables still require the external linker and cgo, but the mailing list would be a better place to ask if this is even expected to work this way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another blog post about statically compiling Go programs that use CGo:
[Linking Golang Statically](http://blog.hashbangbash.com/2014/04/linking-golang-statically/)

It says:

> But for that example, we just have to add the '-static' flag to gcc (and ensure that **glibc-static** package is available).

meaning that your C libraries need to be statically linked as well.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did... see the line in my question which says `go install -x -buildmode=shared --ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' std`.  I do have  version of c runtime for static linking installed.